# Python - How to create a new list and allocate a value based on certain mapping?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

How should i achieve the following using for loop?

Objective:

1. results are to be returned in a new list ---> 'z'
2. 'z' will have same length as 'y'
3. if value in 'y' equals to value in 'v', return the value in 'x' which shared the corresponding location of 'v'

Outcome>>>  z = [0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3]

```
v = ['a', 'c', 'b']
x = [0.2, 0.3, 0.5]
y = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']
z = []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Naive Method

```
z = []
for item in y:
    # find index of item in 'v' list
    item_index = v.index(item)
    # get corresponding value in 'x' list
    value = x[item_index]
    # append in 'z' list
    z.append(value)
```

2. Optimize way:
   you make a dictionary where key from 'v' and value from 'x' list and iterate on 'y' list and make 'z' list

```
search_dict = {}
for i in range(len(v)):
    search_dict[v[i]] = x[i]

z = []
for item in y:
    if item in search_dict:
        z.append(search_dict[item])
```

Comment: thanks alot, the explanation is very clear!

Answer (score 1):

```py
for item in y:
  index = v.index(item)
  if index is not None:
    z.append(x[index])
  else:
    z.append(None)
```

Comment: how should i tweak the syntax if the 'v' is a numpy array instead of a list?